# Angular Universal is using my server's ip address in POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal app (Angular 5.2.11) hosted in Heroku, running in a Node server with express, and I use rate-limiters in all my POST routes checking request's ip in req.header('x-forwarded-for') or req.connection.remoteAddress to limit requests by ip.

The problem is that when those requests are made by the Universal app, the ip that is used is from the machine/netword where my server is hosted. This could lead to wrong rate-limiting to different users, as I could have 100 users requesting my home page at the same time and a rate-limiting of 20 requests in a window of 10 seconds for each POST request present in this page.

Is there any way of passing the original request ip to the Universal App, and use it in the requests headers, making the Universal App acts in behalf of the original user and preventing those wrong rate-limitings?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to whitelist your server's IP.

Comment: I'm using this solution and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No.

Angular Universal is a library for performing server-side rendering.

The code is running on your server, not the browser.

You can't issue a request from your machine and make it appear to be coming from some user's browser. The server would try to respond to the wrong place.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback! And in this case, what could I do to handle the rate-limiting problem? All my requests that fetches data from my DB are secured by rate-limiters, to prevent DOS and other type of attacks, so don't using those limiters are out of question.

Comment: Should I whitelist my server's ip in the rate-limiters?